# Relation between closure of a set and the set of limit points of the interior of the set

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$. It seems intuitive that $\overline{S}$ is equal to the set of limit points of $S^{0}$, where $\overline{S}$ is the closure of $S$ and $S^{0}$ is the interior of $S$. Is this intuition true? Is there a proof for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they may be different. Consider $S$, a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, as the union of the closed unit disk and the interval $[1,2]$.

Then $\overline{S}=S$ (as it is closed), $S^0$ is the open unit disk but the closure of $S^0$ is just the closed unit disk.

The result always holds if $S$ is open. In this case $S^0=S$ so equality of the closures is obvious.